# How to add three tableview cells in a tableview as Subview?

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform, tableview, uitableview

I want to add 2 cells one as header the segue form the previous tableview and the the second cell for details like this prototype .

First Cell class "courseCell"
Second Cell Class "DetailsTVC"

I found many way but it doesn't work I hope someone help

> ```
> I couldn't follow with this instruction
> Initialize your custom tableviewcell - CustomCell1 and CustomCell2
> Since tableviewcell is a subclass of UIView you can add it as a subview.
> ```

```
  [TableCell addSubview:CustomCell1];
          [TableCell addSubview:CustomCell2];
          cell?.addSubview(<#view: UIView>)
         [cell ?.addSubview(<#view: UIView>)]
```

[image]

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView!, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath!, object: PFObject!) -> PFTableViewCell {

    var cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell" , forIndexPath : indexPath) as? courseCell


    if cell == nil
    {
        cell = courseCell(style: UITableViewCellStyle.Default, reuseIdentifier: "cell")
    }

    cell?.name.text = object["title"] as! String!
    cell?.location.text = object["Location"] as! String!






    return cell!
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To accomplish it:

```
TableViewController
 - Tableview
   - TableViewHeader (create a UIView subclass for this view)
   - TableViewContent (datasource)
     - TableViewCell1 (virgin american fligth ...)
     - TableViewCell1 (departs los angeles)
     - TableViewCell1 (arrives new york)
```

Note that you dont need XIB file to your tableviewController

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure why your question title mentions 3 and your question only mentions 2 but from what I can understand based on the image, it appears you want the header to be the title of the course and the rest of the cells to be the details of the course.

To create a header for your TableView you can create a custom "HeaderCell" as you would create a custom cell and then use it in the method which specifies the Header:

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView?{
     //set the title, image or whatever you want for your custom header cell
}
```

Now you can use another custom TableView cell as you normally do to show the details.

**Tutorial:**

http://www.ioscreator.com/tutorials/customizing-header-footer-table-view-ios8-swift